# Find the solution for the spring-mass problem $y′′+9y=\cos(3t)$. Solve with initial conditions $y(0) = 0$, $y′ (0) = 0$. Using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I first took the Laplace transform of each part then getting $s^{2}Y+9Y=\frac{s}{s^{2}+9}$ then solving for Y, I got $Y=\frac{s}{(s^{2}+9)^{2}}$ but don't know how to simplify that to something that can be transformed back.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\frac{s}{(s^2+9)^2} = \frac{d}{ds}\frac{-1}{2(s^2+9)}$

Answer (score 0):

With convolution
$$\dfrac{s}{(s^2+9)^2}=\dfrac13\dfrac{s}{s^2+9}\dfrac{3}{s^2+9}=\dfrac13\int_0^t\cos 3x\sin3(t-x)\ dx=\dfrac16t\sin3t$$

Answer (score -1):

If you let k=3, then you can use that fact that L.T. t*sin(kt) = 2ks/(s^2+k^2)^2  or in your case, 2*3*s/(s^2+3^2)^2  -> 6s/(s^2+3^2)^2    which if you invert should lead to (1/6)t*sint(3t). Try that.

Answer (score -1):

$$\mathcal{L}\{t \sin kt\} = - \frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{\sin kt\} =
- \frac{d}{ds}\left( \frac{k}{s^2+k^2} \right) = \frac{2ks}{(s^2 + k^2)^2}$$

Comment: Please, avoid link-only answers. Type an explanation.

Comment: Hello there. For various kinds of reasons, the answer with a link only may not be accepted, since some users might not be able to see it. Take a few minutes to learn MathJax and type your explanation.